# How to use imported functions in examples

Tags: r, dependencies, package

I have a package that imports functions from another package.  I can use those functions without a qualifier in regular code, but not in examples, it seems.  To demonstrate:

Here's my low-level package that will export function `a`.

```
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)

create("lowlevel")
cat(
  "#' A function in lowlevel pacakge.
#' 
#' Nothing interesting.
#' @return 1
#' @export
a <- function() 1
",
  file = "lowlevel/R/a.R"
)
```

Here's my high-level package that wants to use `a` in an example.

```
create("highlevel")
cat(
  "#' A function in highlevel package.
#' 
#' Nothing interesting.
#' @return 2
#' @examples
#' a() + b()
#' @importFrom lowlevel a
#' @export
b <- function() 2
",
  file = "highlevel/R/b.R"
)
```

Now we build and install the packages:

```
roxygenize("lowlevel")
roxygenize("highlevel")
install.packages(build("lowlevel"), repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages(build("highlevel"), repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

When I run the example, I get an error.

```
library(highlevel)
example(b)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "a"
```

`highlevel` does know about that function, since the `NAMESPACE` file contains the line:

```
importFrom(lowlevel,a)
```

I can make the example work by give a fully qualified name, `lowlevel::a` but this makes it clunky to read.

Is there a way to use imported functions in examples without qualifying their names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of importing a function is to make it available to other functions in your package, that's why you don't have a problem using `a` in the package code.

If you want to use the function in examples, you have to make the function available to the user in the global environment, i.e. you either need to export it or use `library(lowlevel)`.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting, as suggested by Heather and [by Jenny](https://twitter.com/JennyBryan/status/620864896142561280), seems to be the way forward.

You also need to create a dummy help page in the `highlevel` package for the re-exported function.  A [good example](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/blob/master/R/utils.R) is the `tidyr` package reexporting `magrittr`'s pipe operator.

```
#' Pipe operator
#'
#' See \code{\link[magrittr]{\%>\%}} for more details.
#'
#' @name %>%
#' @rdname pipe
#' @keywords internal
#' @export
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @usage lhs \%>\% rhs
NULL
```